# Hide lables, textboxes and combo boxes on MS Access form

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am using MS Access 2007.

How can I hide labels, text boxes and combo boxes in a form when I click a button on another form?

Here is what I have already tried but getting an error: application-defined or object-defined error:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Form!frmDetails!Label105.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Combo110_Label.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Combo110.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Label27.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails![First Name].Visible = False
Form!frmDetails![Second Name].Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!LastName.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails![ID type_Label].Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Combo43.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails![ID No].Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Label33.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Address.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Address2.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Address3.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Label39.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails![Contact No].Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Label112.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Combo113.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!Label113.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!cboStatus.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!cmdSave.Visible = False
Form!frmDetails!cmdPrint.Visible = False

End Sub
```

regards.

joseph

Answer (score 0):

Are all these controls on the same form on which the button you are using to hide? If so you can simply use Me.`controlName`.Visible

apart from that, you are using Form!`formName`!`controlName`.Visible where it should be, **Forms**!`formName`!`controlName`.Visible

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Forms!frmDetails!Label105.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Combo110_Label.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Combo110.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Label27.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails![First Name].Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails![Second Name].Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!LastName.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails![ID type_Label].Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Combo43.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails![ID No].Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Label33.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Address.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Address2.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Address3.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Label39.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails![Contact No].Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Label112.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Combo113.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!Label113.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!cboStatus.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!cmdSave.Visible = False
    Forms!frmDetails!cmdPrint.Visible = False
End Sub
```